# Сброс D-Link DES-3200-10 до заводских

Tags: маршрутизатор, консоль

Ситуация вкратце такова...  Есть маршрутизатор D-Link DES-3200-10, с настроенными неизвестно как портами, пароли и логины неизвестны, настройка и конфигурация портов неизвестна. По собранным мануалам и советам делаю так: подключаю консольный COM to COM кабель, он же RS-232, открываю Putty ставлю VT100+ опцию, затем открываю консоль в режиме Serial. Вынимаю из маршрутизатора шнур питания затем вставляю, на экране в консоли идет загрузка, затем, как прописано во всех советах, в тот момент когда console индикатор перестает мигать на маршр. и в консоли побежали точки, я пробовал зажимать (Shift + 6), пробовал (Shift + 3), вообщем результат один и тот же - ни в какой сброс до заводских он не входит и не реагирует, просто догружает точки, появляется предложение ввести логин и далее он не реагирует абсолютно ни на что, ни на какие нажатия клавиатуры, но что примечательно, это то, что в крайние 2 порта можно воткнуть WAN и LAN и интернет будет, значит настроены они не вовнутрь, и во время предложения в консоли ввести логин, когда нет реакции, втыкаешь WAN и LAN и интернет все равно нормально продолжает работать. Значит проблем с зависанием нет, а потому неизвестна причина отсутствия отклика на клавиатурные нажатия. Кто может помочь с этим узким вопросом?

Comment: может разъем плохо распаян, вы хоть какой-нить ввод в эту консоль смогли отправить ?

Comment: http://www.dlink.cc/d-link-switch/how-to-the-reset-the-password-on-d-link-des-3526.html последний коммент